# XML marshalling not working if different nodes appear in between

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I have below `ejb-jar.xml` which I am trying to map to POJO. It just maps only one MDB and one Session bean though xml has many.

**ejb-jar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd"> 
    <display-name>TradeEJBs</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <description>Trade Session EJB manages all Trading services</description>
            <display-name>TradeEJB</display-name>
            <ejb-name>TradeEJB</ejb-name>
            <home>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.ejb.TradeHome</home>
            <remote>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.ejb.Trade</remote>
            <ejb-class>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.ejb.TradeBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        </session>
        <session>
            <description>Trade JDBC Session EJB manages all Trading services</description>
            <display-name>TradeJDBC</display-name>
            <ejb-name>TradeJDBC</ejb-name>
            <home>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.session.TradeJDBCHome</home>
            <remote>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.session.TradeJDBC</remote>
            <ejb-class>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.session.TradeJDBCBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        </session>
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>TradeStreamerMDB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.ejb.TradeStreamerMDB</ejb-class>
            <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Topic</message-destination-type>
            <message-destination-link>TradeStreamerTopic</message-destination-link>
            </message-driven>
        <session>
            <display-name>KeySequenceEJB</display-name>
            <ejb-name>KeySequenceEJB</ejb-name>
            <local-home>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.ejb.LocalKeySequenceHome</local-home>
            <local>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.ejb.LocalKeySequence</local>
            <ejb-class>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.ejb.KeySequenceBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        </session>
        <message-driven>
            <display-name>TradeBrokerMDB</display-name>
            <ejb-name>TradeBrokerMDB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>org.apache.geronimo.samples.daytrader.ejb.TradeBrokerMDB</ejb-class>
            <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
            <message-destination-link>TradeBrokerQueue</message-destination-link>
        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

**Tester Class:**

**(EjbJarType, MDBModule,SessionModule POJOs are in place with proper Xml annotations)**

```
public class XmlMarshallingTester {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    String configFilePath = "C:\\SampleProject\\ejb\\src\\main\\resources\\META-INF\\ejb-jar.xml";
    EjbJarType ejbJarBean = (EjbJarType) marshal(configFilePath.toString(), EjbJarType.class);
    Map<String, MDBModule> mdbModeulMap = EJBXMLBeanUtil.getMdbDetails(ejbJarBean);
    Map<String, SessionModule> sessionMap = EJBXMLBeanUtil.getSessionBeanData(ejbJarBean);
}


public static Object marshal(String filePath, Class<?> targetClass) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException,
IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);

    JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
    module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module);

    Object obj = targetClass.newInstance();
    Object beans = xmlMapper.readValue(fi, obj.getClass());
    return beans;

}
```

}

However, if the xml file contains all the same type of nodes grouped sequentially (as below), it maps all the MDBs and Session beans as expected.

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
       <!-- some data -->
    </session>
    <session>
       <!-- some data -->
    </session>
    <session>
        <!-- some data -->
    </session>
    <message-driven>
        <!-- some data -->
    </message-driven>
    <message-driven>
        <!-- some data -->
    </message-driven>
</enterprise-beans>
```

So, is there any mechanism/way we can follow for reading all the XML nodes in the order as is and mapping to POJO? Pointers appreciated!

Comment: @M.Deinum added mapping code. Container is not doing it, so looking for alternative.

Comment: If your container isn't doing it then why bother with an ejb-jar.xml etc. in the firstplace? If you need to work around this you either are using the wrong container, or the wrong technology.